# Automated build with docker-compose (Application+mySQL server)

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose

I have some problems while building an automated build for my web application, using mySQL. 
I will use the example from https://github.com/ehazlett/docker-sample-java-mysql-tomcat. 
This is my `fig.yml` file:

```
db:
  image: orchardup/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_USER: java
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: java
    MYSQL_DATABASE: javatest
  ports:
    - "3306"

dbinit:
  image: orchardup/mysql
  entrypoint: /bin/bash
  volumes:
    - .:/host
  command: -c "sleep 4; mysql -u java --password=java -h mysql javatest < /host/init.sql; exit 0"
  links:
    - db:mysql

app:
  build: .
  links:
    - dbinit
    - db:mysql
  ports:
    - "8080"
```

And this the simple `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ehazlett/tomcat7

COPY dbtest /opt/tomcat/webapps/dbtest
```

Now, in order to manually run it I should run these commands:

```
docker run -d -P -e MYSQL_USER=java -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=java -e MYSQL_DATABASE=javatest --name mysql orchardup/mysql

docker run -ti --rm --link mysql:mysql -v $(pwd):/host --entrypoint /bin/bash orchardup/mysql -c "sleep 4; mysql -u java --password=java -h mysql javatest < /host/init.sql; exit 0"

docker build -t javatest .

docker run -ti -P --rm --link mysql:mysql javatest
```

I would like the the applciation would run just by typing:

```
docker-compose up
```

Is there any way to do that?
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For ordering of running your docker containers you need to set [**depends_on**](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#dependson).

For your case:

```
version: '2'
services:
  db:
    image: orchardup/mysql
    environment:
      MYSQL_USER: java
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: java
      MYSQL_DATABASE: javatest
    ports:
    - "3306"
  dbinit:
    image: orchardup/mysql
    depends_on:
      - db
    entrypoint: /bin/bash
    volumes:
      - .:/host
    command: -c "sleep 4; mysql -u java --password=java -h mysql javatest < /host/init.sql; exit 0"
    links:
    - db:mysql
  javatest:
    build: .
    image: javatest
    depends_on:
    - dbinit
    links:
    - dbinit
    - db:mysql
    ports:
    - "8080"
```

and **run docker compose up** with specific build for `javatest` and run it in detached mode with `-d` (optional):

```
docker-compose up --build -d javatest
```

just keep in mind containers will not wait for  startup of `db` just for *"start container"*.

In this case you need to modify entrypoint and create additional script that will wait for connection - checking opened ports for example. - check [wait-for docker suggestion](https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/)

---

**AFTER EDIT:**

I have added full sample how you `docker-compose` should looks like. I added `version` and `services` with correct formatting for `yaml` files.

So back to what you want to do:

```
(1) docker run -d -P -e MYSQL_USER=java -e MYSQL_PASSWORD=java -e MYSQL_DATABASE=javatest --name mysql orchardup/mysql  
(2) docker run -ti --rm --link mysql:mysql -v $(pwd):/host --entrypoint /bin/bash orchardup/mysql -c "sleep 4; mysql -u java --password=java -h mysql javatest < /host/init.sql; exit 0"
(3) docker build -t javatest .
(4) docker run -ti -P --rm --link mysql:mysql javatest
```

***Explanation:***

In  the `docker-compose`,  `db` is doing step `(1)`, `dbinit` is doing step `(2)` and is depended on `db` and service `javatest` is doing steps `(3)` and `(4)` because you build `javatest` image and run it with links like in step `(4)` and also service `javatest` is depended on `dbinit` so it will wait until startup of container (with image `orchardup/mysql`).